# Small dot appears when I try to hide background color using max-width

Tags: php, html, css

I want to get rid off small dot that appear when I use max-width to hide red background before session "del" exists.

Here's my php that shows a messeage saved in session:

```
 <?php
 session_start(); 
 echo "<table id='delpos'>";
 echo "<td id='del'>" . $_SESSION["del"] ."</td> "; 
 echo "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

Before session "del" is existed I need to hide its background color.. So this css doesn't show background-color. I use max-width + max-height, but it shows a little red dot!

```
 <style>
         #del {
         background-color:red ;
color:white;
max-width:20px; // these hide red background color, but show a tiny red dot! 
max-height:6px; // 


}



#delpos  {
margin-top:60px;
margin-left:30px;
position:absolute;


}

</style>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It needs TRs and you should remove the whitespace before and after the dots: `"<tr><td id='del'>".$_SESSION["del"]."</td></tr>"`

Comment: Better yet would be to only define the color on a css class, and only include that class in the html if needed.

Comment: This exact question was asked multiple times yesterday (and subsequently deleted). It looks like you've posted it again with no modification. Were you not satisfied with the responses?